# Flex 1 : height is not fixed to remaining space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a "boxHeader" which height is fixed to 64px and a "boxcontent" which I want height to be fixed to the remaining space.

My problem: if the height of the children in the "boxContent" exceed the height of the remaining space, it will also increase the height of "boxContent". And I don't want that, I want the children of "boxContent" to respect the max size (and add scroll)

Edit: The children inside "boxContent" are React Components, I have a "Sider" of Ant Design containing multiple Panel's Collapse AND I have a Content side by side. I want to add a scroll bar on the Sider AND on the Content so both Sider and Content have overflow-y: auto

Can you help me ?

Here the code

```html
          <div id="container">
              <div id="boxHeader">
                <HeaderArea />
              </div>
              <div id="boxContent">
                {...}
              </div>
          </div>
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100% !important;
  min-height: 100% !important;
```

```css
#boxContent {
  /* height: calc(100vh - 64px); this works, but i don't want to calcule the size*/
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: auto;
  background: white;
}
```

```css
#boxHeader {
  flex: 0 0 64px;
}
```

```css
body{
 height: 100vh; /*100% is also tested*/
}
```

Comment: `overflow: scroll`

Comment: I have already a overflow-y: auto on the children

Comment: What children are you talking about? Please present issues like this in form of a _proper_ [mre], not just several snippets that might lack context.

Comment: overflow auto should be set on boxcontent, not on the children

Comment: I have edited, the problem is i can't put overflow on the boxContent because I want a scroll bar on both the 2 children of boxContent

Answer (score 0):

You can give #boxContent **max-height** and **overflow-y: scroll** with these two I think it is going to work. But If it is not can you add your HTML so that I can look and fix it. I hope this line of code fixes your problem.

```
#boxContent {
  max-height:300px; //(for example)
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: auto;
  background: white;
}
```